# Windows Phone 7 Ads not showing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, ads

I have created an application where i have placed out the adcontrols. I have also configured the IDs for my application though yet no ads are displaying after the change. I have both tested it through the emulator and on my own Windows Phone yet the ads are not showing, what could be the problem?

Comment: What do you see in their place?

Comment: Currently right now the ads are just when starting the application, marking the borderline of the ads and then everything on the adcontrol goes blank and transparent.

Comment: See what happens in test mode.  Application ID: test_client, AdUnitId: Image480_80

Comment: I have already tried it in test mode and everything works fine the  Microsoft ad text pops up and shows both on the emulator and on the windows phone.

Comment: Could it act this way if the advertisement control is placed in the layoutroot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem still persists! Though i know why now and it was nothing with wrong codes or anything.

Microsoft are having problems with their adserver and several people are having the same issues as me.

Seems like this has all begun now in january 2013. People cant even see the test Adcontrols anymore and neither can i. This is a problem with Microsoft that they have to resolve.

Im posting this link to their forums so you can read more and understand that several others have similiar problems with the Adcontrols. Hope this helps!

http://community.bingads.microsoft.com/ads/en/publisher/f/32/t/74426.aspx

Regards William!

Comment: People cant see the test adcontrol coz.. MS ads are limited to few regions only. Ads are not available in India and other places.If u change your device region to US then ads starts coming up.This is what happened to me.. U should start using Google AdMobs!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. What worked for me is setting the height and width of the AdControl in the code too (not just in xaml).

This might not work for.. so to clearly understand where you are going wrong add adcontrol.erroroccured function. My code goes something like this.

```
 public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        String AppId = SResources.Ad_App_ID;
        String AdUnitID = SResources.Ad_Unit_ID;
        sAdControl.AdUnitId = AdUnitID;
        sAdControl.ApplicationId = AppId;
        sAdControl.Width = 480;
        sAdControl.Height = 80;
        sAdControl.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Advertising.AdErrorEventArgs>(sAdControl_ErrorOccurred);
    }

    void sAdControl_ErrorOccurred(object sender, Microsoft.Advertising.AdErrorEventArgs e)
    {
           string error=e.Error.ToString();
    }
```

Hope this helps!! :)

Comment: Great i will try it out! Though the variables SResources and the sAdControl how did you implement those? since im just getting errors on those variables when testing the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I implemeted

```
void sAdControl_ErrorOccurred
```

to discover that capability were missing, so I added `ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER, ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER, ID_CAP_MEDIALIB, ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT` , an now it works good.